# Runge Kutta Procedures for Incompressible Navier Stokes

Tags: runge-kutta

I was playing a little bit with the Runge-Kutta procedure for the Incompressible Navier-Stokes equation and came up with something strange, so I would like to know where I'm wrong or doing something I shouldn't.

Let's consider
$u_i = u^n + \Delta t \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}a_{ij}F(u_j)u_j - c_i \Delta t G \phi_i $

where $F$ is the right hand side operator of the Navier-Stokes equation and $G$ is the discrete gradient operator.

So if I want to find a pressure equation, I should apply the divergence $M$ operator both sides

$Mu_i = Mu^n + \Delta t \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}a_{ij}MF(u_j)u_j - c_i \Delta t MG \phi_i $

and by employing the incompressibility constraint in the inner stages and of course for the $u^n$ (i.e. $M u^n = 0$ and $Mu_i = 0$), I get

$ MG \phi_i = \frac{1}{c_i} \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}a_{ij}MF(u_j)u_j$

Let's define $L = MG$ as the discrete laplacian operator, so that

$ L \phi_i = \frac{1}{c_i} \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}a_{ij}MF(u_j)u_j$

I know that if I solve this pressure poisson equation, I would get the $\phi_i$ lagrange multiplier that allows me to project the velocity into a divergence free field.

But since I need the gradient of the pseudo-pressure, what if I write something like

$ \phi_i = \frac{1}{c_i} \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}a_{ij}L^{-1}MF(u_j)u_j$

$ G\phi_i = \frac{1}{c_i} \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}a_{ij}GL^{-1}MF(u_j)u_j$

but

$GL^{-1}M = G(MG)^{-1}M = GG^{-1}M^{-1}M = I$

so I get that

$G\phi_i = \frac{1}{c_i} \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}a_{ij}F(u_j)u_j$

that implies that $u_i = u_n$, hence I'm not advancing in time ?? I don't know where am I wrong. Thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying the inverse of the Laplacian $L$ and $G$

$$ G\phi_i = \frac{1}{c_i} \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}a_{ij}G L^{-1}MF(u_j)u_j, $$

would violate some previous assumpions

$$ M u^n = 0 ,\quad Mu_i = 0, $$

since

$$ 
\begin{align}
L^{-1}M u^n &\ne 0 ,\quad L^{-1}Mu_i \ne 0,\\
(MG)^{-1}M u^n &\ne 0 ,\quad (MG)^{-1}Mu_i \ne 0,\\
G^{-1}M^{-1}M u^n &\ne 0 ,\quad G^{-1}M^{-1}Mu_i \ne 0,\\
G^{-1} u^n &\ne 0 ,\quad G^{-1}u_i \ne 0.\\
\end{align}
$$

and

$$ 
\begin{align}
GG^{-1} u^n &\ne 0 ,\quad GG^{-1}u_i \ne 0,\\
u^n &\ne 0 ,\quad u_i \ne 0. \quad \square
\\
\end{align}
$$

The correct equation should be

$$
G\phi_i = \frac{1}{c_i} \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}a_{ij}F(u_j)u_j - 1/\Delta t (u_i - u^n).
$$

See your first equation.

**Edit (see the comment)**:

Suppose you have a divergence/gradient operator, we call it $D$, with a divergence free $u = c$ (constant).

Then it holds

$$
 D u = 0.
$$

Now we apply the inverse of the divergence/gradient operator and naively assume that a matrix-vector multiplication with a zero vector results also in a zero vector

$$
\begin{align}
 D^{-1} D u &= D^{-1} 0,\\
  u &= 0.
\end{align}
$$

However, this contradicts the assumption $u=c$.

The only logical conclusion from this is that the discrete divergence/gradient operator is **not invertible** on its own without further assumptions, e.g. boundary conditions.

Or in other words: The indefinite integral of zero is not zero but constant c.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have a few questions though. If $M u^n = 0$  and the matrix multiplication is associative, shouldn't be $L^{-1}Mu^n = 0$ too ? Also, in the last equation you wrote, is it missing a $\Delta t$ at the denominator for $u_i$ and $u^n$ ?

Comment: That is an interesting question, see my edit.

Comment: I got it thanks, indeed $D$ is singular, otherwise there will be no chance other than $u = 0$ for the equation $Du = 0$ to have a solution, as well as $L$ his $L^{-1}$ does not exist, and writing it as $L^{-1}$ is just only "a way to say" solve the following system, but I'm not allowed to do any particular mathematical manipulation with it, right? big thanks anyway

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, I added the $\Delta t$